# Angular: how to use pipe with Location

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In Angular, [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) is *"A service that applications can use to interact with a browser's URL."*

It offers a `getState()` method which providers *"the current state of the location history"* and a `subscribe()` method so one can subscribe to the *"platform's `popState` events."*.

These are both useful, however I'm wondering how I can access the observable of the Location so I can `.pipe` to it and use some rxjs operators before using `.subscribe` on it

Answer (score 4):

Propbably not the cleanest solution but as the Location API doesn't offer anything, why not:

Subscribe to router, map to location state:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const stateObservable = this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => this.location.getState())
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular library doesn't expose private internal [_subject](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a5a9b408e2eb64dcf1d3ca16da4897649dd2fc34/packages/common/src/location/location.ts#L58) as observable of `Location` class.

As workaround you can create a helper to propagate the result of `subscribe()` method to Observable:

```
import { Location, PopStateEvent } from '@angular/common';
...
const locationToObservable = (location: Location) =>
    new Observable((observer: Observer<PopStateEvent>) => 
         location.subscribe(state => observer.next(state)));
```

Usage:

```
constructor(private location: Location) {
  locationToObservable(location).pipe(map(state => ...))
}
```

Comment: Very much this !